# Why do satellites never run out of power?

Tags: artificial-satellite, power, solar-power

Why do the satellites never run out of power do they have batteries that are charged by sunlight everyday? Also they transmit so much information across the globe.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite#Power_subsystem

Comment: What makes you say that satellites never run out of power?

Comment: because they keep transmitting data from telephone signals to movie channels and have no source of energy except the sunlight once they are in a orbit around the earth

Comment: @sonukumar And why do you think sunlight isn't a source of energy?  Solar cells were originally developed for space use!  They produce considerably more power with no atmosphere in the way, never go behind clouds and the night in space is always short.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange!  I think your question is very good, but some people didn't like the wording. Something like "How long can communications last?" or even better "What are the things that limit the useful lifetime of a communications satellite?" is better.  The "never run out..." part causes problems because it's not really true.

Comment: thanks i will keep in mind but english is not my mother language will try better wording

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, satellites may kind of run out of power when their solar panels stop working properly because they have degraded with age. Then we lose connection with them and they become just trash in orbit which is [endangering](http://www.bu.edu/synapse/2012/10/26/space-debris-a-universal-problem/) other satellites and most importantly the ISS.

So yes, satellites use solar energy and it is enough, since those in space are much more efficient. At 500 kilometers a satellite is not exposed to **direct** sunshine for more than 38% of the time. Also on Earth you encounter with cloudy weather, storms and so on.

Comment: They also run out of gas for their maneuvering thrusters and drift off station, or use up all their coolant and become too warm to function properly.